# cocos2d-x removed child to be added again will not worked

Tags: cocos2d-x

```
scene->removeChild(sprite);//removeChild(sprite, false) and removeChild(sprite, true) all tried    

scene->addChild(sprite);
```

the sprite will not be seen. What's happening?

Comment: what you want to implement !!?? .You want to add your sprite again after removing once ??

Answer (score 8):

It seems that your child is simply destroyed after being removed from the scene. In cocos2d-x there is a objective-c-like reference counting system, that will reduce reference count on this sprite after it's being removed from parent. If counter reaches `0` value, node will be destroyed. Make sure that your sprite is not null before call `scene->addChild(sprite);`

```
sprite->retain();
scene->removeChild(sprite);
scene->addChild(sprite);
sprite->release();
```

Every time you call `retain` by yourself, you have to call release after it to prevent leaks.

Comment: thanks, do you know how to keep it not null, even it is removed?

Comment: you are welcome. you can mark this answer as correct to allow others to find it easier

Comment: But if i declare pointer `Sprite *sprite` on header file and create this sprite on the code. After `removeChild` this sprite still is not null. I use `if(!sprite)` to check but it still exist. So when this pointer will be release?

Answer (score 2):

After removing sprite you need to retain, and after adding again you need to release.

```
sprite->retain();   
scene->removeChild(sprite);
scene->addChild(sprite);
sprite->release();
```